# Google Kickstart 2013 Round B Problem Sudoku Checker gives a wrong answer, yet it is working

Tags: c++, sudoku

https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/0000000000434ad7/00000000004347b3 
Sudoku is a popular single player game. The objective is to fill a 9x9 matrix with digits so that each column, each row, and all 9 non-overlapping 3x3 sub-matrices contain all of the digits from 1 through 9. Each 9x9 matrix is partially completed at the start of game play and typically has a unique solution. 
Given a completed N2xN2 Sudoku matrix, your task is to determine whether it is a valid solution. A valid solution must satisfy the following criteria:

Each row contains each number from 1 to N2, once each. 
Each column contains each number from 1 to N2, once each. 
Divide the N2xN2 matrix into N2 non-overlapping NxN sub-matrices. Each sub-matrix contains each number from 1 to N2, once each.

My code:

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;


 int main()
{
int i, j, k, no, n, sum, t[36][36], validsum;
cin >> no;
for (k = 0; k < no; k++)
{
    cin >> n;

    for (i = 0; i < n * n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n * n; j++)
        {
            cin >> t[i][j];
        }
    }

    bool valid = 1;
    
    validsum = ((n*n)*(n*n+1))/2;
    sum = 0;

    if (valid == 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; (i < n * n) && valid == 1; i++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (j = 0; (j < n * n) && sum < validsum; j = j+1) {
                sum += t[i][j];
            }
            if (sum != validsum)
                valid = 0;
        }
    }

    if (valid == 1)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < n * n && valid == 1; j++)
        {
            sum = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < n * n && sum < validsum; i++)
            {
                sum += t[i][j];
            }
            if (sum != validsum)
                valid = 0;
        }
    }

    cout << "Case #" << k + 1 << ": ";
    if (valid == 1)
        cout << "Yes" << endl;
    else
        cout << "No" << endl;
}
}
```

My results:

```
Case #1: Yes
Case #2: No
Case #3: No
```

Example results:

```
Case #1: Yes
Case #2: No
Case #3: No
```

Is it because it's not fast enough?

Comment: Are there only 3 cases? Or are there more cases?

Comment: Hint: your code is wrong. It gives the wrong answer for some cases.

Comment: This site indicates if you fail because of a wrong answer (WA) or because it is too slow (TLE). What message did you receive?

Comment: I received a "Wrong answer" message

Comment: Can you think of a case where your program gives the wrong answer? I can.

Comment: You are not checking the sub-matrices. Here is an example you can work with: https://wandbox.org/permlink/bZIwsEbAeXAU2dhf The expected result is `No`.

Comment: Testing the sums is not enough. `2 + 2 = 1 + 3` for example.

Comment: I added a second example regarding Damien's correct comment: https://wandbox.org/permlink/jXi2UnomkH4WkBJ4 Both expected results are `No` but your code returns `Yes` in both tests.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @jabaa you forgot to check the sub-matrices.

Moreover, checking the sums is not enough, as for example `1 + 3 = 2 + 2`.

An efficient solution consists in checking, in each line, column or sub-matrix, that no number arrives twice.

This is efficient, at the condition to first check that all numbers are in the good range `[1, n^2]`

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

bool check_line (int sudo[36][36], const int &n, const int &n2, const int &line) {
    std::vector<int> vali(n2 + 1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        int num = sudo [line][i];
        if (vali[num]) return false;
        vali[num] = 1;
    }
    return true;
}

bool check_col (int sudo[36][36], const int &n, const int &n2, const int &col) {
    std::vector<int> vali(n2 + 1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        int num = sudo [i][col];
        if (vali[num]) return false;
        vali[num] = 1;
    }
    return true;
}

//  line and col represent the position of the first cell of the submatrix
bool check_sub_matr (int sudo[36][36], const int &n, const int &n2, const int &line, const int &col) {
    std::vector<int> vali(n2 + 1, 0);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            int num = sudo [line+i][col+j];
            if (vali[num]) return false;
            vali[num] = 1;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

bool validity (int sudo[36][36], const int& n, const int& n2) {
    // First check validity of numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
            int number = sudo[i][j];
            if ((number < 1) || (number > n2)) return false;
        }
    }
    // Check lines
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        auto check = check_line (sudo, n, n2, i);
        if (!check) return false;
    }
    // Check columns
    for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
        auto check = check_col (sudo, n, n2, i);
        if (!check) return false;
    }
    // Check sub-matrices
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j) {
            auto check = check_sub_matr (sudo, n, n2, i*n, j*n);
            if (!check) return false;
        }
    }   
    return true;
}

int main() {
    int sudo[36][36];
    int nt;
    std::cin >> nt;
    
    for (int t = 1; t <= nt; ++t) {
        int n, n2;
        std::cin >> n;
        n2 = n*n;
        for (int i = 0; i < n2; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n2; j++) {
                std::cin >> sudo[i][j];
            }
        }
        auto valid = validity (sudo, n, n2);
        std::cout << "Case #" << t << ": ";
        if (valid) std::cout << "Yes" << std::endl;
        else std::cout << "No" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't return correct answers in some cases. You have to check the sub-matrices, too and you can't check using a sum. Here are three test cases to demonstrate the problems in your code:

```
3
3
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5
3
5 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2
6 7 2 1 9 5 3 4 8
8 5 9 7 6 1 4 2 3
1 9 8 3 4 2 5 6 7
4 2 6 8 5 3 7 9 1
7 1 3 9 2 4 8 5 6
9 6 1 5 3 7 2 8 4
2 8 7 4 1 9 6 3 5
3 4 5 2 8 6 1 7 9
3
5 3 4 6 7 8 9 1 2
6 7 2 1 9 5 3 4 8
2 8 8 3 4 2 5 6 7
7 6 9 7 6 1 4 2 3
4 2 6 8 5 3 7 9 1
7 1 3 9 2 4 8 5 6
9 6 1 5 3 7 2 8 4
2 8 7 4 1 9 6 3 5
3 4 5 2 8 6 1 7 9
```

Your code returns `Yes` in both cases but the expected result is `No` in both cases.

Comment: It could also be 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5, 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5, ..... Everything adds up to 45, so it must be valid!

Comment: @user253751 Yes, that's what I mean with _"you can't check using a sum"_

Comment: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 is more obviously broken, much easier than trying to spot the duplicates in your examples

Comment: @user253751 Yes, you're right. This demonstrates the problem very clear.